# Clojure - How to check if type hints in protocols are correct?

Tags: clojure, protocols, type-hinting

How to check if I the type hints I have put to my code are correct?

It seems like even if I put wrong type hints it works without any warnings:

```
=> (defprotocol Qqq (^Qwerty qqq [this ^String q]))
Qqq
=> (qqq (reify Qqq (qqq [this q] (+ q 5))) 7)
12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I remember, type hints aren't used right now, but could be used in future... Here is cite from official description at [clojure.org](http://clojure.org/datatypes)

---

fields can have type hints, and can be primitive:

- note that currently a type hint of a non-primitive type will not be used to constrain the field type nor the constructor arg, but will be used to optimize its use in the class methods
- constraining the field type and constructor arg is planned